# Unknown Issue on sending data through tcpclient?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp

look at this code :

```
  private bool SendPack(byte[] _Data)
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkStream clientStream = Servertcp.GetStream();

            byte[] Pack = new byte[4 + _Data.Length];
            byte[] len = BitConverter.GetBytes(_Data.Length);
            len.CopyTo(Pack, 0);
            buffer.CopyTo(Pack, 4);
            clientStream.Write(Pack, 0, Pack.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

the function's behavior is strange! sometimes data is received in client side, sometimes not. the function usually returns true, but in reality no data received, although client is connected to server. when i debuge the function i see that sometimes i lost the pointer after this line :    clientStream.Write(Pack, 0, Pack.Length); i mean the pointer does not return to the lines after write...

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `buffer.CopyTo` a typo, should it be `_Data.CopyTo`?  Are you sure the error lies within the sending code and not the receiving  code (which you do not show)? One way to check might be to use a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [NetMon](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4865) if you are sending between two systems.

Comment: can you provide a compilable and testable example? It's incredibly hard to tell the problem without any tests.